# Changing redux state asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I use redux toolkit and I have my initial state like this:

```
initialState: {
  details: {
    id: "",
    base64: "",
  },
},
```

I want to fetch an image base64 inside of my initial state, whenever user logged in. I decided to do such thing in my axios:

```
axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL_API_LOGIN}`, {
  softWareOrUser: false,
  userName: userName,
  password: password,
})
  .then((r) => {
    if (r.data.resCode === 1) {
      dispatch(setDetails({ ...details, id: r.data.Data.Id.toString() }));
      ImageFetchingHandler(r.data);
    }
  })
  .then((d) => {
    navigate({ pathname: "/main" });
  })
  .catch(() => {
    alert("user name or password is incorrect");
  });
```

This is how I fetch image base64:

```
const { details } = useSelector((state) => state.axiosdetails);
const ImageFetchingHandler = ({ token }) => {
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL_API_FETCH_IMAGE}`,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "DotNet-Timeout": 30000,
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
      id: details.id,
    }),
  })
    .then((d) => {
      Cookies.set("userImage", JSON.stringify(d.data), {
        path: "/",
        expires: 3,
        sameSite: "strict",
        secure: window.top.location.protocol === "https:",
      });
    });
};
```

I have a problem, the `ImageFetchingHandler` sends `id` value as an empty string even though `redux developer tools` shows the actual id value.

[Redux developer tools shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPZqy.png)

What is the problem?

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: show `setDetails`

Comment: What is value of `r.data`? `ImageFetchingHandler` is passed only object and destructures a `token` property. What `id` value are you referring to in `ImageFetchingHandler`? Please share a more complete [mcve].

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka ok. just a moment

Comment: @DrewReese I refer to `id: details.id` in `JSON.strignify` section. which gets data from redux.

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka `reducers: {
    setDetails: (state, action) => {
      state.details = action.payload;
    },
  },`

Comment: Ok, so you are accessing a value in an enclosure it seems. `ImageFetchingHandler` should access the store synchronously if you are not passing in the values it needs.

Comment: @DrewReese do you mean in enclosure of object? but I selected `id` specifically. `details.id`

Comment: where do you defined `axiosdetails`

Comment: That's outside the scope of `ImageFetchingHandler`. When you call `ImageFetchingHandler` in the `axios` promise chain it has the current values closed over in scope. If you are able to share a more complete [mcve] we could probably better help you. It would be nice to see how these code snippets relate to one another.

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka directory structure is like this: 1 App folder. 2 child directories called `slices` and `store`. `axiosdetails` created as a seperate js file in `slices` and imported in `store`

Comment: @DrewReese of course. what details should provide? I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that the `r.data` object has already all the details you need, specifically that it has the `r.data.Data.Id` property that you are setting the `id` state to that you are later immediately attempting to access in the `ImageFetchingHandler` function.

```
dispatch(setDetails({ ...details, id: r.data.Data.Id.toString() }));
ImageFetchingHandler(r.data); // <-- id is in the data
```

In addition to accessing `data.token` in `ImageFetchingHandler` you can also access `data.Data.Id` for the id value for the payload.

```
const ImageFetchingHandler = ({ Data: { Id: id }, token }) => {
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL_API_FETCH_IMAGE}`,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "DotNet-Timeout": 30000,
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({ id }),
  })
    .then((d) => {
      Cookies.set("userImage", JSON.stringify(d.data), {
        path: "/",
        expires: 3,
        sameSite: "strict",
        secure: window.top.location.protocol === "https:",
      });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a side effect for `details` and check whether `details.id` is present or not. If present then run the fetch function.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(details.id) {
    // call API here
  }
}, [details])
```

As soon as the component renders the details field is empty that point of time. Asynchronously the `details` field get it's actual value.